# Angularjs: is this the right place to use a directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I've recently switched from jQuery to Angularjs and I am in the process of re-coding some pagination logic for the links ("Next", "Previous", etc.) that were written in jQuery-style Javascript previously.

Each link has an **ngIf** condition (for example, the "Previous" link won't show if you're on page 1) plus an **ngClick** event, which essentially updates a scope variable called $scope.pagination.position that determines which results are displayed in the table.

My original code was something like this (simplified for clarity):

**Template**

```
<a ng-if="pagination.position > 0" ng-click="pagination.first()">First</a>
```

**Controller**

```
$scope.pagination = {
   first: function() {
      this.position = 0;
   }
}
```

Then I learned more about directives, and how most DOM elements that aren't static HTML should be created using a directive. So I switched each link (since each has it's own display rules and behaviour on clicks) to its own directive, like so:

**Template**

```
<a pagination-first></a>
```

**Directive**

```
app.directive('paginationFirst', function() {
   return {
      link: function(scope,el,attr) {
         scope.pagination.first = function() {
            scope.pagination.position = 0;
         }
      },
      replace: true,
      template: '<a pagination-first ng-if="pagination.position > 0" ng-click="pagination.first()">First</a>'
   }
});
```

I'll cut straight to the chase : am I doing directives wrong? All that's happened, from my perspective, is I've flipped from having logic in my template to having a template in my logic, and I've defined the click event function in the directive rather than in the controller.

Is this even an appropriate time to be using a directive?

I'd like to learn best practices, so I'd love to know if I've missed the point and if the original templated-based ngIf and controller function approach was fine, even with longer and more complex ngIf conditions than the one shown.

Comment: are you facing some issues in directive ? Also i'll suggest to create a directive for Pagination instead for each page

Comment: Not as such, I just failed to see any benefit in separating the pagination links out into directives and assumed it was because this wasn't the best use case for directives. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If I want to add specific behaviors to a dom or dom list  then I normally create a directive. As per angular js perspective the dom manipulation should only be done through directive (For me it is the best place, sometime I have to disobey this due to my lack of knowledge ). I specially found directive use full while creating a widget. In one of my project there was a part where a section is dedicated to display an image and also upload the image. I just use the directive on the top div, with the help of link function I attached the event handlers to various child dom. And as my project doesnot require an isolated scope (as this widget was all used in a single project and the outer scope was under my control) . So it worked like a charm. I cerarted the directive once. And used that widget through rest of the project as it's behavior and design (of the widget ) was same through out the project. For the pagination widget you can create a directive. Take the directive attibutes value as the input of the pagination parameters. Like calling script, limit offset. Container identifier to update the content. Then you can solely concentrate on the pagianation behavior. But from my experience (as I am also not so experienced in angular js), sometimes it becomes a little hectic to develop a directive and and use that throughout the project. As in some places we need to modify the behavior of the directive. And for this it may breaks elsewhere. But I know as I learn more I will be more efficient to handle this kind of situation. Hope my experience will help you.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I did some reading on directives yesterday and gained some clarity on the matter.